How to access the element of a JSON array by index
In a QML project, I need to read and access the elements of an array of objects from this JSON file:
{
  "params": [
    {
      "id": "1",
      "tag": "aaa",
      "name": "aaaaaa",
      "value": "1.23"
    },
    {
      "id": "2",
      "tag": "bbb",
      "name": "bbbbbb",
      "value": "4.56"
    }
  ]
}

I can do it if I have a single object, but I cannot make it work with an array.
This is what I am doing:
var jsonObj = JSON.parse(dataFile);
var i = 0;   // array index
var elem = jsonObj.valueOf("params")[i]
console.log("params[" + i + "]: " + elem)  //  TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined
console.log("params[" + i + "].id: " + elem.id)  // TypeError: Cannot read property 'id' of undefined

Note that I am not trying to access the 'name' field.
How can I access the object fields?
Note:
My question includes the valueOf function, which is not mentioned here.

This question is similar to: How can I access and process nested objects, arrays, or JSON?. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

var jsonObj = JSON.parse(dataFile); 
var i = 0; 

var elem = jsonObj.params[i];

if (elem) { 
    console.log(i + ".id: " + elem.id); 
} else {
    console.log("No element at " + i);
}

You can use jsonObj.params[i] instead of use valueOf method. Accessing directly elem.id can caused TypeError if elem is undefined value.

Can valueOf be used for the same purpose (with my syntax being incorrect), or is yours the only syntax to be used?
